# Deduplication in angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have several controllers that have some duplicated code that acts directly on the controller object (this). It looks roughly like this:

```
geekApp.controller( 'ReviewsCtrl', 
  [ 'moduleLoader', function ( moduleLoader ) {

    // controller specific code removed, above

    // the stuff below here is essentially duplicated in a few controllers
    that = this;
    this.loader = [];

    this.getModule = function () {
      var loaderPromise = moduleLoader.getModule( this.url, this.params );
      //add loader promise to this so I can pass it to angular-busy in the template
      this.loader = loaderPromise;

      loaderPromise.success( function ( data ) {
        that.data = data;
    } );
  };

  this.getModule();

} ] );
```

Most of the shared code was moved to the module loader, but that's still a lot of duplication. But basically all of the duplicated code directly modifies the controller, so my usual approach, offloading code to a service, won't really work, unless I pass `this` into the service, which I understand to be a bad practice.

I could use `angular.extend` to make a base controller with this function, but I feel like there should be a better way.

What is the "angular way" do deduplicate this code?

Comment: Yes you can extend from a base one. But you should consider to use the Service to keep stuff that will be shared along multiple controllers. Services are intended to this.

Comment: I am using a service for most of this already, but I thought passing "this" or $scope to services was discouraged. while the code is the same between the controllers, the data is not.

Comment: If you have to pass the controller to the service, you are not decoupling stuff as you should. Service should turn your controller "dumb", without lose It power.

Comment: not sure what your goal is here.  why do you have duplicate controllers to start with.  you should think abstracting more, not to find a way to duplicate faster.

Comment: You see what I'm doing above, right? Basically everything I'm doing is setting values on the controller, so that those can be accessed in the template. Those controllers have other non-duplicate code as well, of course--each with its own functionality, in addition to the shared functionality.  So they aren't really duplicate controllers--just different controllers with some similarities. I'd like to avoid the duplication "the angular way", but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @Karptonite Then you should create a BaseController and then extend each new one from this Base controller.